# Does VMware Workstation support guest OS access to built-in Bluetooth?

Tags: usb, virtualbox, bluetooth, vmware

I have an Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop host OS on a laptop with built-in Bluetooth and I installed VMware 17. Inside the VMware I installed Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop.

I have a bluetooth headset and I want to connect it to the guest OS, but I can't. I tried to tick the "Share Bluetooth devices with the virtual machine" under VM > Settings > USB Controller but the guest OS just keep on searching and can't find any device.

Now it appears that method is supposed to be used for Bluetooth USB dongle and not for built-in Bluetooth.

Is it possible for a guest OS to access the built-in Bluetooth of the host OS in VMware Workstation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes (you do need Workstation 8).

VMWare Player -> Settings -> USB Controller -> Share Bluetooth devices with the virtual machine.

There are restrictions:

- Outgoing connections only. So no support for passing Headphones, headsets,hands-free audio devices classes of Bluetooth devices.
- The host does the pairing process; the guest works without a PIN.
- The guest sees a generic VMware brand radio. Any vendorspecific options are unavailable.